# bigquery and gdelt database: how to count the number of event and number of mentions

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

Is `count(*)` code the number of event.
But in my data the are the same as `count(NumMentions) as Mentions`,
In fact, mentions may be more than events.
what's wrong with my code

```
SELECT
YEAR,
ACTOR1COUNTRYCODE as Country1,
Actor2CountryCode as Country2,
count(NumMentions) as Mentions,
COUNT(*),
From gdelt-bq.full.events_partitioned
Where
_PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2013-12-31')
AND ACTOR2COUNTRYCODE='CHN'
GROUP BY YEAR,Country1,Country2
ORDER BY  YEAR,Country1,Country2
```

Comment: What does each row of table represent? Is each row a distinct event or is each row a distinct mention? Did you want to COUNT() the number of mentions or is mentions an INT64 that you want to SUM() instead?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to change your `COUNT(NumMentions)` to `SUM(NumMentions)`. COUNT() will count the number of records, but SUM() will actually sum the integers.

```
SELECT
  YEAR,
  ACTOR1COUNTRYCODE as Country1,
  Actor2CountryCode as Country2,
  SUM(NumMentions) as Mentions,
  COUNT(*)
From gdelt-bq.full.events_partitioned
Where
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2013-12-31')
    AND ACTOR2COUNTRYCODE='CHN'
GROUP BY YEAR,Country1,Country2
ORDER BY  YEAR,Country1,Country2
```